# How to create JavaScript async render html like Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I googled a lot trying to create external JavaScript for my users.

My project is I want to allow my users fetch content from my website by use JavaScript.

I want my code exact like Google AdSense style

```
<script async src="//mysite.com/api/content.js"></script>
<!-- Links add -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:180px;height:90px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
 data-ad-slot="xxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Could anyone please help, how can I coding on my content.js (mysite.com/api/content.js) to output any content into "ins.adsbygoogle" class.

If I use document.write("say something"); it works fine, but not for async and it is not on ins.adsbygoogle that I want to render it.

Comment: There are an awful lot of ways. In the script you can simply target the element and work in it... `document.querySelector('ins.adsbygoogle')` and take it from there.

Comment: Tried to search but not found the way to add html in it yet.

Comment: Ok I can do it now, thank you very much

document.querySelector('ins.adsbygoogle').innerHTML = 'some thing';

Comment: You could also use methods like `appendChild` to append creatred elements or different nodes to it etc...

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you have is that your **async** script may load after the script tags in your document. One approach to solving this is to listen for the load event before running any code. The alternative, which the googleads code appears to use is to have some javascript run in the async script at the end of the file.

Imagine you have an html page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script async src="testasync.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>hello</p>
    <myblock></myblock>
    <p>done</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For example, in the testasync.js file this code should appear at the end and triggers everything to load once the asynchronous load has completed:

```
(function(){
  addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ main_function() });

  function addEvent(element, eventName, fn) {
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
    else if (element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, fn);
  }
})();
```

Now when your javascript loads this function will be run, attaching an event listener to the page so that once the page is ready and your HTML is in place you can run the actual functionality.

At the top of the testasync.js, your main_function would use javascript to do something like this for example:

```
main_function = function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('myblock')[0].innerHTML = '<p>present something here</p>';
};
```

This functionality would appear at the top of the testasync.js file.

If you create the testasync.js file and the html file you should see this work.

Feel free to edit this response if you need to expand on anything.

Comment: A thousands thanks Phil, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: You are very welcome. If this answered your question, please feel free to accept this response as the correct answer.